# Terraform handle multiple lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a requirement for creating aws lambda functions dynamically basis some input parameters like name, docker image etc.

I have been able to build this using terraform (triggered using gitlab pipelines).

Now the problem is that for every unique name I want a new lambda function to be created/updated, i.e if I trigger the pipeline 5 times with 5 names then there should be 5 lambda functions, instead what I get is the older function being destroyed and a new one being created.

How do I achieve this?

I am using [Resource: aws_lambda_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function)

Terraform code

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "executable" {
  function_name = var.RUNNER_NAME
  image_uri     = var.DOCKER_PATH
  package_type  = "Image"
  role          = role.arn
  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you currently have along with any errors.

Comment: @MarkoE - I have updated code snippet. I am not getting any errors. What I want to achieve is for every unique RUNNER_NAME a new lambda should be present

Comment: You would have to use either a list or a map as the values for runner names. Then, you could use `count` or `for_each`.

Comment: The number of lambdas which I require is dynamic in nature. I wont have the entire list with me.

Comment: Yes, so you can add new values to the variable. Unless I misunderstood what dynamic means.

Comment: What I mean by dynamic is that this pipeline might be triggered from some other process which will pass some parameters. So updating the variable every-time might not be a good fit for me. Is there anyway terraform to decide change of which parameter values warrants a deletion + creation vs creation alone?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using some kind of a backend to store the state file? Terraform makes a decision based on the change and what it sees in the state file. But you cannot have more than one instance of anything using the same variable name unless you use either `count` or `for_each`. You could maybe write a module and invoke it but that would require some kind of a `count` or `for_each` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding on how terraform works.

Terraform maps 1 resource to 1 item in state and the state file is used to manage all created resources.

The reason why your function keeps getting destroyed and recreated with the new values is because you have only 1 resource in your terraform configuration.
This is the correct and expected behavior from terraform.

Now, as mentioned by some people above, you could use "count or for_each" to add new lambda functions without deleting the previous ones, as long as you can keep track of the previous passed values (always adding the new values to the "list").

Or, if there is no need to keep track/state of the lambda functions you have created, terraform may not be the best solution to solve your needs. The result you are looking for can be easily implemented by python or even shell with aws cli commands.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I misunderstood the usage of terraform. As a solution what I went with is creating different state files for the different resources. So every resource had its own state-file and any update was limited to that particular resource